# Probability of at least 3 of 5 events being successful

Tags: probability

Suppose I have five events, each with their own distinct probability of success. For example:

Event 1: 60%

Event 2: 40%

Event 3: 25%

Event 4: 80%

Event 5: 35%

How can I calculate the probability that **any three or more** events succeed? The events do not need to succeed in any particular order

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll just need to do a whole lot of calculation. But basically you need to figure out the probability of all 5 events to happen (just multiply them all together), add to that the probability of exactly 4 events to happen (which can happen in 5 different ways of course), and add to that all the ways exactly 3 events happen (that'll be in ${5\choose 3}=10$ ways, so that' more involved).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

1. Make a loop over numbers : $[0,2^5]$
2. For each iteration we have a new number, say it has binary digit vector ${\bf d} = [d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_5]^T$:

   1. Sum binary digits $s = \sum_kd_k$.
   2. Accumulate multiplicatively $(1-p_k)^{1-d_k}(p_k)^{d_k}$. You can avoid branches by storing $1-p_k$, $p_k$ next to each other in arrays and use digit $d_k$ for indexing.
   3. If sum in 1) above is $\geq 3$ then add. You can avoid branching by doing the comparison and do a multiply-add with the logic value

      ```
      (sum >= 3)
      ```